# How to execute a block of code in cordova when app is closed

Tags: javascript, android, ios, cordova

I am develop an app in `Cordova`. I would like execute a block code when my app is closed, like notification or connect to a server **REST call**.
I did some searches and saw that many people talk about cordova-plugin-background-mode, that work fine when the app is in background, but my problem is when the user close the app. 
How I can execute javascript code in this conditions?

Thanks

Comment: When an app is closed, no further execution of code happens.

Answer (score 0):

Your requirement is not clear to me , are you trying to do task when app go in background or when app got killed.

If you want to do something after app got killed then your cordova activity will get `callaback` like `onPause` and `onDestroy` you can trigger a `service` or simple java thread from `onDestroy` and do your task.

If you want to do something in background then you can use codova custom plugin to do task for you with the help of `AsyncTask`,`Service` or `Threadpool`.